# Can the Play Store (in /system/priv-app/) be reinstalled with a newer version?

Tags: google-play-store, google-apps, system-apps

Tapping on the build number in the Play Store doesn't really update it anymore on my device; I have no idea why. 
I've been trying to sideload the apk which just installs the newer version into /data/app/ but after several reboots i still don't see the newer version.

So yes, is it possible that I just delete the one from the /system/priv-app/ and push the newer version in it?

Strangely, other Google apps that didn't come preinstalled just fails to install through the rom's old Play Store (version 5.5.12)and just comes up with a "-504" error. The same happens when trying to update preinstalled ones.

My phone is on stock Android 5.0 from the manufacturer rooted with SuperSU 2.82.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No, it depends on the version of thd play store and the Google play services, both usually work together and can not work with the wrong version, so try to replace both apps...

You should use OGapps ( Open Google Apps ) , it's designed for custom ROMs.

You might have problems with the version designed only for DATA installations, and may need an alternative app from another custom ROM that is the same version.

Comment: Ok I have sideloaded the latest Play Services - it's successfully installed on /data/app/ and I can see the right version on my app list. As I've said I'm _not_ on a custom rom, so I guess I shouldn't be using OGapps..? (Can I replace the Play Store manually now I have the latest Play Services?)

Comment: Anyone? (Also, everytime I sideload an app through TWRP flashable it gets "optimized" every boot. And the whole optimizing stage takes at least 15 minutes.)

Comment: The fact that you now have a modified ( customized ) ROM  means that you ARE on a custom ROM... The normal Gapps will do extra security checks to see if your using a device with vulnerabilities like ROOT Access.

Comment: Okay... That means I should really flash an [OpenGApps](https://opengapps.org/) package on my rom to fix this? I am now downloading a 5.0 nano package that includes the Play Store and services... 
My phone is a Lenovo so the now customized stock rom in it is of course Lenovo's custom firmware

Comment: Try that :) ..........

Comment: Aight I'll try it :) hope it won't cause a bootloop because I've heard some getting a bootloop on flashing GApps on a stock firmware from manufacturers...

Comment: be careful... you can just replace the Google Play Services & Play Store application

Comment: Okay I've just replaced it. But now at every boot, the "Optimizing app 1 of 3" takes so long to finish. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You need to odex the applications...

Comment: You aren't doing anything wrong, it's optimizing the applications because they aren't Odexed, You need to odex the 3 applications that are being optimized.... Optimization is similar to an Odex that is stored in the User Data partition instead of alongside the system app... It just makes the app launch quicker... Don't Odex Google Play Services .. it states this in the APK manifest

Comment: Okay, so i need to odex the Play Store but not Play services? I'll just leave the Play Services as it is when it was replaced...?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so, apparently Google has been [blocking "uncertified" devices](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-blocks-gapps-uncertified-devices-custom-rom-whitelist/) from installing and updating Google Apps, but they provided a way to somehow "[whitelist](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-fix-device-not-certified-by-google-error/)" devices running custom roms and modified stock roms.

This enables the aforementioned devices to still install and update GApps, but in the Play Store they still appear uncertified.

My Lenovo A7000 Plus unfortunately got caught in this particularly new Google scheme because  I've recently flashed a more recent pre-rooted stock rom for my Lenovo device and added it to Google's whitelist. Now I can install and update my Google apps, but Play Store stayed outdated.

Even though my Google Play Services *has* updated in the background itself, Play Store remained untouched.
Somehow the only problem here is that I wasn't aware of this beforehand.

Also, here are some things I was speculating about:

- [some users](https://www.xda-developers.com/how-to-fix-device-not-certified-by-google-error/#comment-3827846742) have reported being uncertified even when running stock roms with unlocked bootloaders.
- the GSF (Google Services Framework) ID used in whitelisting the device changes every factory reset/wipe and thus at every reset the whitelist process must be done again
- This new policy seems like one of the stepping stones to Google adapting Apple's system...